# jQuery - $.ajax success callback data is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery $.ajax to post a simple contact form to a php script. I'm trying to evaluate the response and based on that, either replace the whole form with a "thank you" message or populate an "error" div with the problems. The success callback is being called, so (I think) there is no error, but the data is nevertheless empty.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = '#' + $(this).closest('form').attr('name');
        $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/index1.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(name).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == 'yes') {
                $('#error').html(data);
            } else {
                $(name).html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure the Success function (not the error one) is running because I get the alert even if I remove the error function. Also if I remove that alert line I don't get any alerts. And the form contents are being replaced with an empty div, so it looks like it's running smoothly.

Also, if I replace "alert(data)" with "alert('hello')" that does show. So Data is empty!

If I try to post the form directly (without jQuery), I get a response from the php page - either "Please enter your name. Please enter your e-mail. Please enter your company." Or "Thank you! Your message has been submitted."

Everything is on the same domain.

Why is Data empty? For the past 6 hours, I just can't get my head around this.

I haven't set any global ajax settings. Before posting here, I've also tried this with JSON just as suggested in one of the answers and the same result - empty response. I tried xml as well.

index1.php has a ton of code related to the other forms on the site. The gist of it:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) exit();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    switch (basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
//define required fields, fields to e-mail in the form, success message, form div id...
    }
}
if (is_array($required)) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($required as $req) {
        $error = '';
        if (empty($_POST[$req])) {
            switch ($req) {
//adjust error message based on name of field...
                    default: $error = 'Please enter your ' . $req . '.';
            }
            $errors[] = $error;
        }
    }
}
    if (empty($errors) && is_array($fields)) {
        //decide to which e-mail address to send everything based on the form input
       $headers = "From: ...";
       $subject = "Inquiry";
    $body = "The following information was submitted:\n\n";
    foreach ($fields as $a => $b) {
        if (is_array($_POST[$a])) {
            $body .= sprintf("%s: %s\n", $b, stripslashes(implode(', ', $_POST[$a])));
        } else {
            $body .= sprintf("%s: %s\n", $b, stripslashes($_POST[$a]));
        }
    }
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if (!$send) $msg = 'We encountered an error sending your message, please go back and try again. If the problem persists, please call us.';
}
$error = 'no';
if (is_array($msg)) {
    $msg = implode(' ', $msg);
    $error = 'yes';
}
header('Content-type: text/html');
echo $error . ' ' . $msg;
}
```

I'm obviously going to change the final text being echoed to something that can actually be meaningfully parsed, but at this point I'm just trying to get something to show in the success callback.

One thought - could $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] be my issue? I'm switching from prototype and it wasn't a problem there, so I took it for granted here. If so is there a way to identify the page from which the form was submitted?

[UPDATE] Tried adding a "default" scenario under the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] switch statement to no avail, so I'm guessing this isn't the issue.

Comment: whay is in index1.php can i see ?

Comment: I'm assuming your submit button is called `submit`? Would that get populated in your AJAX call? If index1.php is exiting on the first line that would explain the empty response. What if you echo something back from the `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: I've changed data: $(name).serialize() to data: $(name).serialize() + '&submit=Submit' and it's working great now. Thank you!

Comment: i might be a little late here, but IE does not recognize HTTP_REFERER in ajax calls, don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your *AJAX* is that you are overriding the default submit button action, so the *submit* button does not really submit the data, the *Javascript* that does it and looking the *Javascript* code, the `$_POST['submit']` will never be set when the *PHP* page is called:

```
var name = '#' + $(this).closest('form').attr('name');
    ...
    data: $(name).serialize(),
```

The only *POST* info send here is the variable `name`, try to send `submit` field with some value and you will see a different response.

You can also check if this is really happening changing the `exit()` by `die('empty submit')`.

Comment: thank you!!! that solved my issue. I still don't understand why it wasn't an issue with prototype (I was using the same jquery code but sending it to a prototype function instead of the ajax part) but at least it's figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

try add the `dataType: "text"` option and the complete callback below to check your response

```
complete: function(xhr, status) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);    
}
```

Comment: the complete callback is also returning empty. I removed all the other "alert" to make sure that's the one that's running.

Comment: Also tried to alert the status in the complete callback, and it shows "success"...